# Setting Map Type in Android, constant problems

Tags: android, google-maps

I am playing around with com.example.mapdemo, all java files compile except the LayersDemoActivity.java which contains

```
private void setLayer(String layerName) {
    if (!checkReady()) {
        return;
    }
    if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.normal))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    } else if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.hybrid))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    } else if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.satellite))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    } else if (layerName.equals(getString(R.string.terrain))) {
        mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    } else {
        Log.i("LDA", "Error setting layer with name " + layerName);
    }
}
```

the compiler doesn't recognizes MAP_TYPE_NORMAL, MAP_TYPE_HYBRID etc. constants. What is it wrong?

Comment: this  mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NORMAL); should be map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
mMap.setMapType(MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

should be

```
mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
```

Same for other map types also

Check the doc under change the Map Type

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Comment: Or import constants using static syntax.